# Generic swapping of "string" in C

Tags: c, pointers, generics, swap

I was looking at a video lecture about how to do a **generic** swap using `memcpy()` and `strdup()`.

The generic swap code is as follows :

```
void GenericSwap(void* ptr1, void* ptr2, int size){

    char buf[size];
    memcpy(buf,ptr1,size);
    memcpy(ptr1,ptr2,size);
    memcpy(ptr2,buf,size);
}
```

and we call it like this :

```
char* h = strdup("fred");
char* w = strdup("wilma");
GenericSwap(&h,&w,sizeof(char*));
printf("h : %s\nw : %s\n\n",h,w);
```

This swapped "fred" and "wilma" as a whole string. That is, h points to "wilma" and w points to "fred" now.

However, when i change the code to this :

```
char h1[10] = "fred";
char w1[10] = "wilma";
GenericSwap(&h1,&w1,sizeof(char*));
printf("h1 : %s\nw1 : %s\n",h1,w1);
```

I get "wilm" and "freda" for `h1` and `w1`. I am passing address of stuff holding the address of the 1st element of the array, just like the proper working code up top, but this isn't working so nicely as the top one did.

Is it Something about `h1` and `w1` being mere pointers, and not pointer-to-pointers ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to change the address of the arrays, which you cannot do. Array variables act as `const` pointers to their data, they cannot be changed.

Instead, you're swapping the first `sizeof (char *)` (which seems to be 4 on your system) characters.

Basically for

```
char h[8] = "foo";
```

The two statements

```
printf("%p\n", (void *) h);
```

and

```
printf("%p\n", (void *) &h);
```

will print *the same* address, i.e. the expression `&h` evaluates to the address of the first element, just like `h`. There is no separate variable that holds the array's address, for you to change.

Comment: ok ! Then, lets say in a hypothetical compiler which **does** allow this change of address of an array , in that case, will the '&h' method give the correct answer ? as the 'strdup()' method is giving ?

Comment: @Somjit Such a compiler would not be compiling the programming language C, so of course I don't know.

Comment: @unwind where is the OP trying to change the address of which array?

Comment: @iharob In the code line `GenericSwap(&h1,&w1,sizeof(char*));`, where `h1` and `w1` are arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. That answered what i was trying to ask. So in C(im using 99), &h and h , where h is a pointer to a char array, are for all purposes the same ? right ?

Comment: @Somjit Not for all purposes, no. `sizeof &h` and `sizeof h` do different things, for instance. It depends on the context.

Comment: umm.. i'm probably asking for something that's gonna go above me, but can u give/point to an example where these are different ?

Comment: `char x;` -> `sizeof(x) == sizeof(char)` whereas `sizeof(&x) == sizeof(char *)` and `sizeof(char *) != sizeof(char)`.

Comment: @Somjit I assumed you meant `h` to be a `char` array. For e.g. `char h[1024];`, the expression `sizeof h` will evaluate to `1024`, but `sizeof &h` will be the same as `sizeof (char *)`, i.e. typically 4 or 8. The *numerical value* of the two expressions `h` and `&h` will be the same, but `sizeof` knows the difference anyway.

Comment: Okay ! So wrt `sizeof()` , h and &h are different. Thanks !